# JUnit test is successful in IntelliJ but failed in Maven

Tags: java, maven, junit, intellij-idea

I wrote a JUnit test which is executing successfully in Intellij and it is passed. But if I run mvn clean test that particular test is failing. To be more specific the task is to check if the request is sent or not. So when I run the test in IntelliJ the test passes with Status code 201(Successful). But when I run mvn clean install it is showing it as status code 400(Bad request).

I searched online regarding this, but couldn't find solution. Please help me.

Below is the code. It is failing at the first assertion: `assertEquals(response.getStatus(), Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode());`:

```
@Test
public void testUpdateMultiValueAttributes() throws URISyntaxException {


    String createPayload =
            "{\n" +
                    " \"id\": 9,\n" +
                    " \"email\": \"" + "ismith@zzz.com" + "\",\n" +
                    " \"profile\": {\"userAttrs\":[" +
                    " {\"CUST_ATTR_MULTI_VALUE\": \"CUST_ATTR_MULTI_VALUE_3\"}" +
                    " ]}" +
                    "}";
    MockHttpRequest request = MockHttpRequest.put("/subscribers/9");
    request.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    request.content(createPayload.getBytes());
    MockHttpResponse response = new MockHttpResponse();
    dispatcher.invoke(request, response);
    LOG.error(response.getContentAsString());
    response.toString();


    assertEquals(response.getStatus(), Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode());
    SubscriberDto subscriber = null  ;
    try {

        subscriber = MarshallingUtils.unmarshallJSON(new TypeReference<SubscriberDto>() {
        }, response.getContentAsString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }

    Collection<SubscriberAttributeDto> customAttributes = subscriber.getProfile().getUserAttrs();

    if (customAttributes!=null)
    assertTrue(customAttributes.contains(new SubscriberAttributeDto("CUST_ATTR_MULTI_VALUE", "CUST_ATTR_MULTI_VALUE_3")));
```

Comment: could you give some more information? Code snippets, etc.

Comment: Do you have a different version of Java in your %PATH% than the one you use in your IDE?

Comment: And where does it fail in your code? I'd say it is at the first assert, but...

Comment: It fails at the first assertion assertEquals(response.getStatus(), Response.Status.CREATED.getStatusCode()); Here in intellij the status is well satisfied. But in mvn clean test response is showing as 400 instead of 201

Comment: Do you have a proxy set in IntelliJ? Do you have a different maven profile running on the command line? Are you using the same version and settings for maven within intellij and on the command line? Are you using the same version of java in intellij and on the command line?

Comment: I dint set proxy in IntelliJ. In intelliJ I am using mavne test-compile to debug the unit test. on cammand line the Java version is 1.6.0_65 whereas in intellij it is 1.6.0_57. Does this make difference

Comment: What about the version of Maven?

Comment: maven version is 3.0.4

Comment: Is the maven log showing any exception stack traces?

Answer (score 0):

Using `createPayload.getBytes("UTF8")` may solve the issue